# D3.js method chaining command dosn't work when I split it, it works

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, method-chaining

I am new in D3.js, 
when i use this code it doesn't work,(it is part of the redraw, when running for first time it works good when calling redraw again it works unexpextedly)

```
var rows=tbody.selectAll('tr').data(roster);
rows.enter().append('tr');
rows.exit().remove();
rows.selectAll('td').data(function(row) { return columns.map(function(col) {
  return row[col];
});}).enter().append('td').text(function(d) {return d;} );
```

when I break the chain down into smaller it works.

```
var rows=tbody.selectAll('tr').data(roster);
rows.enter().append('tr');
rows.exit().remove();

var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
.data(function(row) { return columns.map(function(col) {
  return row[col];
});});
cells.enter().append("td");
cells.text(function(d) { return d; });
```

any reason or any rule govern this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you are only updating the text on the new cells, not the old ones. When you chain `.enter()` like that, all of the following methods chained apply to the object returned by `.enter()` and that is the enter selection : added cells in other words.

Read [this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)